# Finding $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dk}{k}\sin(c\tau k)\cos(k X)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to show the missing steps involved in the integral:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dk}{k}\sin(c\tau k)\cos(kX)\propto \text{sgn}(c\tau+X)+\text{sgn}(c\tau-X)$$
where $\text{sgn}(x)=\pm 1\ \text{for}\ x \gtrless 0$.
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dk}{k}\sin(c\tau k)\cos(kX)\propto \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin[(c\tau+X)k]}{k}dk+\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin[(c\tau-X)k]}{k}dk $$
Now we can write the first integral as
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin[(c\tau+X)k]}{k}dk \propto (c\tau+X)\ \text{sgn}(c\tau+X)$$
As you see, I'm getting an extra factor.

Can you please what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

$$
I(A)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin Ak}{k}dk=\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_0^c\frac{\sin Ak}{k}dk\\
=\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_0^{Ac}\frac{\sin k'}{k'}dk'
$$
where we have changed the variable to $k'=Ak$.
If $A>0$ we get ([Dirichlet integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral)):
$$
I(A)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin k'}{k'}dk'=\frac{\pi}2{\rm sign}(A)
$$
If $A<0$ we get:
$$
I(-|A|)=\lim_{c'\to-\infty}\int_0^{c'}\frac{\sin k'}{k'}dk'\\=\int_0^{-\infty}\frac{\sin k'}{k'}dk'=-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin k'}{k'}dk'=\frac{\pi}2{\rm sign}(-|A|)=\frac{\pi}2{\rm sign}(A)
$$